# How to expand and loop through a group of

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-update

The following SQL command lists the `hash` values which can be found on multiple objects.

```sql
SELECT *  FROM (
  SELECT 
    MIN(id) AS id, 
    hash, 
    status, 
    count(*) AS count 
  FROM foobar 
  GROUP BY hash 
  ORDER BY count
) AS t 
WHERE count > 1;
```

...

```
+------+----------------------------------+--------+-------+
|   id | hash                             | status | count |
+------+----------------------------------+--------+-------+
| 4523 | e4266978b1d99dffbf3a6e0b880a2c5e |      0 |     3 |
|  828 | 9414c7478416b7a40846d66e12df9370 |      0 |     4 |
|  293 | bfc742499fd97c4c8e36f57cdd0fa0e0 |      0 |     5 |
|  244 | ec408e4678789f7983f83a9c330ab8e4 |      0 |    14 |
+------+----------------------------------+--------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

I want to update the `status` of each item within the groups. For a single group this can be done as follows:

```
UDPATE foobar SET status = 9 WHERE hash = "e4266978b1d99dffbf3a6e0b880a2c5e";
```

How can I update the `status` of each 26 individual items? The solution should run on MySQL at least.

Comment: Which `status` do you want? Currently your query returns a 'random' status!

Comment: You want to update the `status` to 9 for all rows where the hash appears in the table more than once?

Comment: What exactly you want as Output??

Comment: @MartinParkin Yes, I want to set the `status` to `9` for all duplicates.

Comment: Do you mean

    UDPATE foobar SET status = 9 WHERE hash IN (SELECT hash FROM (
      SELECT 
        hash, 
        count(*) AS count 
      FROM foobar 
      GROUP BY hash 
    ) AS t 
    WHERE count > 1)

? It will work in MySQL because MySQL will create a temporary table for the select with the "group by".

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sql
UPDATE foobar
SET status = 9 
WHERE hash IN (
  SELECT hash FROM (
    SELECT 
      hash, 
      count(*) AS count 
    FROM foobar 
    GROUP BY hash 
  ) AS t 
  WHERE count > 1
)
```

It will work in MySQL because MySQL will create a temporary table for the select with the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Find all the hashes that are duplicated and then use that as the criteria for your update query:

```
UPDATE  foobar
  SET   status = 9
  WHERE hash IN (SELECT  hash
                   FROM  foobar 
                   GROUP BY hash 
                   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: I run into *"You can't specify target table 'foobar' for update in FROM clause"*.

Comment: Apologies, I made a mistake in my SQL which I have now corrected - D'Oh!

Comment: I already substituted the **table name** when I tested your SQL statement. The error message remains.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE foobar t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN foobar t2 ON t1.id <> t2.id AND t1.hash = t2.hash
WHERE t2.id IS NOT NULL
SET t1.status = 9
```

Comment: I receive: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `"id" <> t2."id" AND t1."hash" = t2."hash" WHERE t2."id" IS`

Comment: Without `"` I still receive: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `WHERE t2.id IS NOT NULL SET t1.status = 9`.